# I can't find the directory where the images are saved

Tags: flutter

I have a screen that accesses the gallery to select images, after selecting the images, they should be saved in a path that is as follows: ***/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DA34D6CB-8E50-4474-8FDB-BCCB0722F558/Documents/my_images_folder/image_picker_10B6C77B-F45C-4B95-B052-B7E5B1A2E541-11862-00000BDD4E44CA7C.jpg***

The problem is that this directory is not created on the phone. Do you know the reason why the directory is not there when the renamed image was created and saved?

> This is the code:

```
Future<void> saveFilesToInternalStorage(List<XFile> images) async {
  try {

    var statusPhotos = await Permission.photos.request();
  var statusStorage = await Permission.storage.request();

    print('Permiso de fotos: ${await Permission.photos.status}');
    print('Permiso de almacenamiento: ${await Permission.storage.status}');

    if (statusPhotos.isGranted && statusStorage.isGranted) {
      // Obtener el directorio de documentos de la aplicación
      Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

      if (documentsDirectory != null) {
        print('Directorio de almacenamiento interno: ${documentsDirectory.path}');

        // Crear una carpeta dentro del directorio de documentos
        Directory folderDirectory =
            Directory('${documentsDirectory.path}/my_images_folder');
        if (!folderDirectory.existsSync()) {
          folderDirectory.createSync();
        }

        // Iterar sobre las imágenes y guardarlas en la carpeta
        for (XFile image in images) {
          String imageName = image.path.split('/').last;
          String imagePath = '${folderDirectory.path}/$imageName';

          // Copiar la imagen al directorio de la carpeta
          await File(image.path).copy(imagePath);
          print('Imagen guardada en: $imagePath');
        }
      } else {
        print('No se pudo obtener el directorio de almacenamiento interno.');
      }
    } else {
      print('No se tiene permisos para guardar las imagenes.');
    }
  }
```

> These are the permissions I gave to the app:

```
<key>NSFileProviderDomainUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Necesitamos acceder a tus archivos para guardar datos.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>La aplicación necesita acceder a la galería de fotos para cargar imágenes.</string>
```

It tells me that I do not have permission to the photos, but I do have permission created "PermissionStatus.denied"

I hope you can support me.
Thanks.